# How to access all of a file's attributes through Python in Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, attributes

In a Windows 7 system you can right-click the sort columns to look at the details you want to view for a file and you get the following:

[image: Explorer file attributes list]

**Question:** Is there a way to access all of the attributes on that list for a given file using Python?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is closed, but this can be accomplished using win32com.client.Dispatch('Shell.Application') and GetDetailsOf

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You are not likely to get a good answer because Microsoft makes this way too complicated, and their documentation on this topic is some of the worst that they have.

Everything is wrapped up in COM interfaces, and you really need the SDK installed to get all of the headers file needed to access these interfaces from a C style API.

To understand how it really works, you really need to start the [Property System Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728871(v=vs.85).aspx#note_to_implementers)

You will also want to read [Property System Developers Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728870(v=vs.85).aspx)

There is one [C language answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629718/how-do-i-use-ipropertystore-to-access-mp3-metadata-in-windows-with-c)  that I know of for this topic on S/O, though clearly there could be others.

I know it is not a real answer, and it is certainly not Python -- but if you have the real motivation to dig into this, hopefully this is at least a little helpful.

Also not that these extended properties are poorly supported, and tend to disappear under many common usage patterns since they are not really part of the file -- e.g., copy the file using ftp -- lose the extended file attributes.